# Memory-Debuging: How to get locked pages information in user space/kernel space in linux

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Is there any way to get locked pages(virtual memory pages) information in user space/kernel space in linux .

I want to know details like:
Who locked the pages ?
how many pages are locked ?
Process name who locked the page ?

Also let me know the memory debugging techniques in kernel space as well as user space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each page in memory the is flag assigned to it, Virtual memory page is locked using `mlock`, `mlockall()` etc API, it assigned the `VM_LOCKED` flag to page.

Two options to know the locked pages detail:

1. Use cat `/sys/kernel/debug/page_owner >> page_owner.txt`
           To enable debug: `kernel menuconfig PAGE_OWNER=y`
                             add `"page_owner=on"` to boot cmdline.
                             `cat /sys/kernel/debug/page_owner >> page_owner.txt`
2. In linux source code type: `/tool/vm/page-types.c`, then
      compile it and iterate through all pid entries in `/proc/` and use the following option for application:
      `./test -p $PID -L >> test_output.txt`.
      It will give you all page details with flags, then you can find locked pages in memory.