# How to debug/find cma allocation failure reason?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Is there any open source debug methods/patch available for CMA failure debug ?
How to know the reason of CMA allocation failure

Comment: Are you trying to debug declaring (setting up) a CMA region, or debug allocating pages from a CMA region?

Comment: I am trying to debug allocated pages from cma region(movable pages), when try to allocate cma buffer it fails, how to know it fails on migration/page is pinned by other process, how to know/confirm the reason of failure.

Comment: You can configure `CONFIG_CMA_DEBUG` to print out various messages to the kernel debug log when pages are allocated and released from CMA, but it hard to find out what is responsible for allocating the pages.

Comment: CONFIG_CMA_DEBUG already enable not much information.

Comment: There is also a debugfs interface that can be enabled to show a map of allocated pages, configured by `CONFIG_CMA_DEBUGFS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.When the cma_allocation fails it dump backtrace of failure.

### eg.

[   35.360001] page:bef55be8 count:58 mapcount:56 mapping:bc4001dc index:0x3

[   35.366855] flags: 0x8019040c(referenced|uptodate|arch_1|mappedtodisk|unevictable|mlocked)

[   35.375173] raw: 8019040c bc4001dc 00000003 00000037 0000003a b9eb1a98 b9eb1a98 00000000

[   35.383299] raw: be008c00

[   35.385916] page dumped because: VM_BUG_ON_PAGE(PageLRU(page) || PageUnevictable(page))

[   35.393995] page->mem_cgroup:be008c00

[   35.397668] ------------[ cut here ]------------

[   35.402281] kernel BUG at mm/vmscan.c:1350!

[   35.406458] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM

---

[   37.778079] Backtrace:

[   37.780531] [<80360610>] (shrink_page_list) from [<803617c8>] 
(reclaim_clean_pages_from_list+0x14c/0x1a8)

[   37.790093]  r10:b9c6fb88 r9:b9c6fb9c r8:b9c6fb0c r7:8141e100 r6:81216588 r5:b9c6fb9c
[   37.797914]  r4:bf05ffb8

[   37.800444] [<8036167c>] (reclaim_clean_pages_from_list) from [<80352b2c>] (alloc_contig_range+0x17c/0x4e0)

[   37.810178]  r10:00000000 r9:8121e384 r8:814790c4 r7:b9c6e000 r6:0006a000 r5:00081a00
[   37.817999]  r4:b9c6fb9c

[   37.820529] [<803529b0>] (alloc_contig_range) from [<803bd8c8>] (cma_alloc+0x154/0x5dc)
[   37.828527]  r10:00040000 r9:00017c00 r8:fffffff4 r7:00017c00 r6:8147bf24 r5:00009e00
[   37.836347]  r4:00069e00

[   37.838878] [<803bd774>] (cma_alloc) from [<80694188>] (dma_alloc_from_contiguous+0x40/0x44)

[   37.847310]  r10:00000000 r9:80607f30 r8:b9c6fd64 r7:00017c00 r6:17c00000 r5:81216588
[   37.855131]  r4:00000001

[   37.857661] [<80694148>] (dma_alloc_from_contiguous) from [<80218720>] (__alloc_from_contiguous+0x54/0x144)

[   37.867396] [<802186cc>] (__alloc_from_contiguous) from [<80218854>] (cma_allocator_alloc+0x44/0x4c)

[   37.876523]  r10:00000000 r9:b9c6fe08 r8:81216588 r7:00c00000 r6:b94d0140 r5:80607f30
[   37.884343]  r4:00000001

[   37.886870] [<80218810>] (cma_allocator_alloc) from [<80217e28>] (__dma_alloc+0x19c/0x2e4)

[   37.895125]  r5:bd2da400 r4:014000c0
[   37.898695] [<80217c8c>] (__dma_alloc) from [<80218000>] (arm_dma_alloc+0x4c/0x54)

[   37.906258]  r10:00000080 r9:17c00000 r8:80c01778 r7:bd2da400 r6:8148ff6c r5:00c00000
[   37.914079]  r4:00000707

[   37.916608] [<80217fb4>] (arm_dma_alloc) from [<80607f30>] 
[   37.924690]  r5:81490278 r4:81216588

---

You can debug cma allocation failure using this backtrace.

2. Continuously check /proc/pagetypeinfo before allocation and after allocation, it will give you hint if pages are back or not to the initial stage.
3. To get pages information refer below link:-
   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984296/memory-debuging-how-to-get-locked-pages-information-in-user-space-kernel-space/55574578#55574578)
4. stable kernel bug here is the patch [link](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20190524071114.74202-1-minchan@kernel.org/)

According to [link](https://lwn.net/Articles/619865/) :-

This cma mechanism imposes following weaknesses.

1. Allocation failure
   CMA could fail to allocate contiguous memory due to following reasons.

   1-1. Direct pinning
   Any kernel thread could pin any movable pages for a long time. If a movable page which needs to be migrated for a contiguous memory allocation is already pinned by someone, migration could not be completed. In consequence, contiguous allocation could be fail if the page is not be unpinned longtime.

   1-2. Indirect pin
   If a movable page have dependency with an object, the object would increase reference count of the movable page to assert it is safe to use the page. If a movable page which is needs to be migrated for a contiguous memory allocation is in the case, the page could not be free to be used by contiguous allocation.
   In consequence, contiguous allocation could be failed.

In short, cma doesn't guarantee success and fast latency of contiguous memory allocation. And, the core cause is the fact that cma chosen 2nd-class client(movable pages) were not nice(hard to migrate / discard) enough